# Weird JS syntax: math operator in function declaration

Tags: javascript, syntax

I just played with [Twitter API](https://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://example.com&callback=c) and found very weird construction. It's division operator between function name and arguments passing.

```
c/({"count":8098,"url":"http:\/\/example.com\/"});
```

I supposed that this should throw parser exception, but it works − just returning `NaN` instead of `undefined`. Also it works similar with `*` and `-` operators, while `+` returns `c.toString()` (or `.valueOf`, I dunno).
Even more, it's really syntax error thrown if i don't pass object to function. Here's examples:

```
function c() {}
>> undefined

c
>> function c() {}

c/()
>> SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

c/({});
>> NaN

c+({})
>> "function c() {}[object Object]"

c({})
>> undefined
```

I ran this in Chrome, but I belive it works everywhere if Twitter put it in response.
So. Why this even work, and how it works exactly? I believe this somehow releated to function returning value and its implicit type coercion, but I still don't get it.

Comment: It's not really a function definition. It's simply a division operation between whatever is in `c` and an object. Not entirely sure why they're doing that though.

Comment: I know this is not a definition. For jsonp, `c` defined before calling server. This is function **call** instead.

Comment: @Tommi no, it's not a function call. The parentheses in that expression are parsed as ordinary algebraic grouping operators, not the function call operator.

Comment: Thanks to all. I should put some logic inside `c` to ensure it's called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL is not escaped in that API call so twitter reads it incorrectly and creates meaningless syntax. 
If you set the URL parameter to an escaped value (via `encodeURIComponent`) it will produce `c({some:"Object"})` which is a JSONP response - JSONP is inherently a function call and works by injecting a script tag.

So, twitter does not produce this response deliberately, you're passing it problematic parameters and it's not failing gracefully.

As for why dividing a function in an object is `NaN` - in JS generally math operators don't throw very often. JavaScript is telling you - you tried to perform a math operation that doesn't make sense and the result is not a number - NaN.

For the funky results:

```
c/()
```

Is just invalid syntax, simply put you're diving something by nothing, `5/()` would fail equally well.

```
c/({})
```

Diving a function by an object makes no sense, so it is giving you "Not a Number". I can add a spec quote but I don't think there is much more to add beyond "There is no way to interperet this differently".

```
c+({})
```

The `+` operator performs string concatenation in addition to numeric addition - so what's happening here is that `toString` is called for both the function and the object and you see the concatenated result.

```
c({})
```

This is just the return value of the function call

Comment: You're right. I should put some logic in my `c` function to check if it called. `function a() { console.log("in"); };` still returns NaN and don't print "in". Thanks for so quick response. Feel myself too stupid right now.

Comment: Don't feel bad about the question - this is confusing behavior on both Twitter's API and the JavaScript language. Both could have done a better job at letting you know what's wrong.